# Selecting multiple checkboxes with Capybara, weird behaviour

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

I am making an acceptance test on Ruby on Rails 3.0.11 with Capybara 1.1.2, and trying to select two checkboxes in a form.

Here is the view code for the checkboxes (using haml 3.1.3 and simple_form 2.0.4):

```
  = f.input :countries,
            :collection => MusicTeaser.teaser_countries,
            :as => :check_boxes
```

The collection looks like this:

```
[["AT", "at"], ["CH", "ch"], ["DE", "de"], ["ZA", "za"]]
```

And the HTML generated:

```
<div class="input check_boxes optional">
  <label class="check_boxes optional control-label">Countries</label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" id="music_teaser_countries_at" name="music_teaser[countries][]" type="checkbox" value="at">AT
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" id="music_teaser_countries_ch" name="music_teaser[countries][]" type="checkbox" value="ch">CH
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" id="music_teaser_countries_de" name="music_teaser[countries][]" type="checkbox" value="de" checked="">DE
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <input class="check_boxes optional" id="music_teaser_countries_za" name="music_teaser[countries][]" type="checkbox" value="za">ZA
  </label>
  <input name="music_teaser[countries][]" type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

The code to select them looks like this (pretty straightforward):

```
  check 'music_teaser_countries_de'
  check 'music_teaser_countries_za'
```

I expected that, on submit, the `countries` param would look like this:

```
params[:music_teaser][:countries] = ["de", "za"]
```

But it appears as this:

```
params[:music_teaser][:countries] = ["deza"]
```

So it seems like Capybara is doing something wrong when selecting more than one checkbox. Ideas?

Comment: This shouldn't be an issue any more, see:
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/288/
Is it still present?

Comment: I don't have access to this code anymore, so I cannot check it. Thanks a lot anyway :)